# Infinite Background Speed Unity2D

Tags: c#, scroll, infinite-loop, unity-game-engine

I'm getting crazy with an infinite background and its speed.

Basically I would like to control the speed smoothly in order to increase/decrease it.

How can I achieve that?

```
void Start () {
    speed = 0.4f;
}

void Update () {
    float x = Mathf.Repeat((Time.time * speed),1);
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2 (x, 0f);
}

public void IncreaseSpeed(float newSpeed){
    ?
}

public void DecreaseSpeed(float newSpeed){
    ?
}
```

Comment: Can you not just increase and decrease your speed variable in those methods? "speed = newSpeed"

Comment: I can, but it's "jumping" to the new speed and change is visible. I would like to make a smooth transition to the "new speed", without causing a visible weird effect.

Comment: Instead of setting the speed variable to newSpeed, just add a small amount to the current speed. Continue to do that until your speed variable is the desired speed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, I don't think there's any need for you to have separate functions for increasing and decreasing speed. Rather, just have a single one that sets a target speed, and increment/decrement your actual speed as needed each frame until you reach the target.

An example implementation could look like:

```
float speed = 0;
float targetSpeed = 0;
float speedStepSize = 0.1f; // Change as needed based on how quickly speed should change

void Start () {
    targetSpeed = 0.4f;
}

void Update () {
    float x = Mathf.Repeat((Time.time * speed),1);
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2 (x, 0f);

    if (targetSpeed < speed) {
        speed = Mathf.Max(speed - speedStepSize, targetSpeed);
    }
    else if (targetSpeed > speed){
        speed = Mathf.Min(speed + speedStepSize, targetSpeed);
    }
}

public void SetTargetSpeed(float newSpeed){
    targetSpeed = newSpeed;
}
```

(You can also multiply the step size with `Time.deltaTime` if you don't want the speed bound to the frame rate.)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Cool! it does the job, thanks! Is it possible to use values smaller than 0.1f (0.01f) ? I'm receiving a strange behavior if I set speedStepSize to 0.01f (going faster actually). Also, how would you use Time.deltaTime to "ease" the transition to the targetSpeed?

Comment: Glad I could help out. I'm not sure why using values less than 0.1f would increase the rate that the speed changes - logically, it should make it slower, as it takes more steps to go from current to target speed. Adding/subtracting `speedStepSize * Time.deltaTime` won't create an easing effect, but will ensure that the speed changes at a rate independent of the game's frame rate (which is usually desirable). If you do want easing (non-linear rate of change), the approach will be significantly different (and a tad more complex).